# When can you make a bracha mentally?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shulchan-aruch, drinking

The Taz to SA Orach Chaim 62:4 says in exigent cirumstances you can make a bracha mentally instead of verbalizing it:

> מזה יש ללמוד במי שצמא בלילה במטתו שא"א לו ליטול ידיו ולברך יהרהר הברכה בלבו וישתה

SA Orach Chaim 172:1 discusses what to do if you accidentally started drinking and can't make a bracha without spitting out the drink. Some say you should swallow and skip the bracha rishona (or say it afterwards). [Others](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.172.2) say it's best to spit it out. Why doesn't the Taz suggest making the bracha mentally?

Comment: The Kaf HaChaim actually does recommend it: https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.172.1.1

Comment: The classic example is a Baal Keri (back when Ezra's enactment prohibiting him from praying was in effect). See Mishna Berachot 3:4. Whether that allowance was just a way of giving him an option to say a pretend blessing or an actual non-ideal way to say a blessing will affect how useful the method is in other contexts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Pri Migadim [Eishel Avraham 172:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41248&st=&pgnum=129) asks the question and says that some hold since the liquid is no longer really edible, it’s not worthy of a bracha, even with thought. It would seem that according to others, it would indeed work.

The Aruch Hashulchan [209:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.209.5?lang=bi) explains why the Rambam who holds that a person who made a mistake at the end of a bracha but thought the correct one in the beginning, is yotze, because he’s using the thought as a bracha.

> והולך לשיטתו בפרק א' דכל הברכות יוצאין בהרהור בלב בלבד ע"ש, ולפי זה שפיר קאמר: "שבשעה שהזכיר את השם והמלכות שהן עיקר הברכה לא נתכוין אלא לברכה הראויה וכו”,' כלומר כיון דבשעת אמירת השם והמלכות היה בלבו לומר כהוגן, והרי הוא כאלו גמר הברכה בלבו ויצא, ואם כן מה איכפת לנו מה שסיים בפיו שלא כהוגן כיון שכבר יצא בהרהור הלב.

So the Rambam holds it works bdieved, and when there’s no other option, the poskim seem to rely on it.

Comment: I see my question in the משבצות זהב but can't find the answer that it's not worthy of a bracha. Can you point me to it?

Comment: He refers to the Rach who holds that

Comment: Thanks, I see now. But what does he mean by מ"ש בט"ז אות ב?

Comment: He means to refer to the mishbatzos zahav number 2 where he asks the same question and sends you to this piece

Comment: If you can't make a bracha once it's no longer edible, why do we say in the next halacha דבר שנמאס מסלקו לצד אחר ומברך?

Comment: Liquid seems to be worse than that, according to this shita